# How to concatenate input that doesn't go through layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a Keras model with three inputs. Only one of them goes through the first few layers and the other two are concatenated at a dense layer. How would I achieve this without disconnecting the graph? The code is shown below

```
import keras
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
input_1 = Input(shape=(1,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(1,))

x = (Dense(48,kernel_initializer='normal',activation="relu"))(input_img)
x = (Dropout(0.2))(x)
x = (Dense(24,activation="tanh"))(x)
x = (Dropout(0.3))(x)
x = (Dense(1))(x)
x = keras.layers.concatenate([x, input_1, input_2])
x = (Activation("sigmoid"))(x)
x = Model(input_img, x)
x.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam')
```

To give a more general overview of what I'm attempting, I am essentially trying to create a Convolutional Neural Network with additional features added to the dense layer for classification.

Answer (score 0):

Since your model has three inputs, i.e. `input_img, input_1 and input_2` you need to pass a list of these three inputs while defining your model as follows:

```
x = Model([input_img, input_1, input_2], x)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I try to define the input data for training, I get the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_7 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)`  I defined the input as`inputs = ([X_train.reshape(790000,625), input_1[0:790000].reshape(790000,), input_2[0:790000].reshape(790000,)])`